# How to scroll down inside followers popup on Instagram?

Tags: imacros

How can i properly use scroll function inside Instagram popup.
[image]

I used js function to scroll , which didnt worked

```
window.scrollBy(0,800);
```

via Imacros

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY" KEY=34
```

As well before scroll event used to click between users to make popup active and then used scroll, before it worked but for now it's not.

Is there any proper way to scroll inside popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following command may be helpful:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="div.j6cq2" KEY=34
```

Comment: Thank You! Working perfectly

Comment: How do you make it run in Python?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in 2019... Don't change anything!

```
FList = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role=\'dialog\'] ul')
numberOfFollowersInList = len(FList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'))

FList.click()
actionChain = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(random.randint(2,4))

while (numberOfFollowersInList < max):
    actionChain.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()        
    numberOfFollowersInList = len(FList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'))
    time.sleep(0.4)
    print(numberOfFollowersInList)
    actionChain.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()            
    time.sleep(1)
```