# How to scroll down the pop-up follower list in instagram using selenium ? (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, instagram

I tried this

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 80)')
```

but it scrolls only homepage not the popup follower list.

[This is the div section (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBURm.png)

Comment: Can we get some background on the issue? Some more code would be nice along with whatever the ‘pop up followed list is’.

Comment: There is no any issue , Just want to scroll down the pop-up windows of follower list .
Scrolling is new things , so whatever code I wrote can't be useful .

Comment: Okay then, can you provide the link to whatever page you are working with?

Comment: read nicely bro , I'm saying instagram . first go to any instagram page the click followers the one popup window will open , that popup window i need to scroll down with python selenium .

Comment: Sorry about that, but I don’t use Instagram. Let me make an account.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659987/how-to-scroll-down-inside-followers-popup-on-instagram

check this